# Custom countdown view using Animation class

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create something like the image below:

[image]

I need to be able to set a max value, have it count down every second until it reaches 0, display that value, and have the progress bar also move every second.

I tried a bunch of different approaches using this library: [CircleProgressView](https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View), but I end up having to use a Handler and separate threads, and with the Android lifecycle keeping the threads under control is just a total nightmare.

Can this be done using shapes and an animation? I know the animated progress circle is fairly simple, but displaying that number in the middle I haven't been able to do yet.

**EDIT**

So I just found the library has a setValueAnimated method (RTFM)..  It seems like it may solve my issue.  I'm still a bit concerned the library may be more than I need, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To animate your text you can do something like that :

```
public static void animateValue(Context context, final TextView textView, int duration,final double start, final double goal) {
        if (start != goal) {
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat((float) start, (float) goal);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            animator.setDuration(duration));
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    textView.setText(formatPercentage((float)animation.getAnimatedValue()));
                }
            });
            animator.start();
        } else {
            textView.setText(formatPercentage(goal));
        }
    }

    public static String formatPercentage(final Float value) {
        //TODO do your desiredFormat
    }
```

and for your progress something like that :

```
  public static void animateProgress(final Context context, final ProgressBar progressBar, int duration, final int start, final int end) {        
        if (shouldAnimate(context) && start != end) {
            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", start, end);
            animation.setDuration(scaleDuration(context, duration));
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());            
            animation.start();
        } else {
            progressBar.setProgress(end);
        }
    }
```

and for you progress color you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="@integer/progress_bar_circular_inner_ratio"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="true"
            android:thicknessRatio="@integer/progress_bar_circular_thickness">
            <solid android:color="@color/">
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270" >
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="@integer/progress_bar_circular_inner_ratio"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thicknessRatio="@integer/progress_bar_circular_thickness">
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/"
                    android:endColor="@color/"
                    android:centerColor="@color/"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: ValueAnimator looks pretty promising.  Any ideas on the layout resources for creating the design from above?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm starting with just the spinner... and it's weird the animation doesn't start for the first 4 or 5 seconds and then they start and pick up really fast.  If it's set for 60 seconds it goes for about that duration however, the movement of the animation is no where near consistent.  I'm using this in a RecyclerView for what it's worth.

Comment: Do you have the right interpolator ? you can try to put 660 for start and 1000 for goal.. it make the animation smoother

Comment: Ok, yeah that makes sense -- AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.  I'm making some progress now.

Comment: Good don't forget to accept my answer if you are satisfied